# Unable to open Anywhere option from Gatekeeper in order to open apps not from Mac App Store

Tags: terminal, mac-appstore, big-sur, gatekeeper

I was following [this guide](https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-app-unidentified-developer-3669596/) to open a Mac app from an unidentified developer.

So I open Terminal and enter the following code to get the Anywhere option

```
sudo spctl --master-disable
```

This leads to the following output

```
objc[7234]: Class SPExecutionPolicy is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SystemPolicy.framework/Versions/A/SystemPolicy and /usr/sbin/spctl. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[7234]: Class AppWrapper is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SystemPolicy.framework/Versions/A/SystemPolicy and /usr/sbin/spctl. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[7234]: Class AppWrapperPolicyResult is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SystemPolicy.framework/Versions/A/SystemPolicy and /usr/sbin/spctl. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[7234]: Class AppWrapperPolicy is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SystemPolicy.framework/Versions/A/SystemPolicy and /usr/sbin/spctl. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[7234]: Class SPLog is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SystemPolicy.framework/Versions/A/SystemPolicy and /usr/sbin/spctl. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[7234]: Class MIS is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SystemPolicy.framework/Versions/A/SystemPolicy and /usr/sbin/spctl. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[7234]: Class SPExecutionHistoryItem is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SystemPolicy.framework/Versions/A/SystemPolicy and /usr/sbin/spctl. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[7234]: Class SPExecutionPolicyItem is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SystemPolicy.framework/Versions/A/SystemPolicy and /usr/sbin/spctl. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[7234]: Class SPDeveloperPolicy is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SystemPolicy.framework/Versions/A/SystemPolicy and /usr/sbin/spctl. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[7234]: Class GKScanResult is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SystemPolicy.framework/Versions/A/SystemPolicy and /usr/sbin/spctl. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

but doesn't seem to enable the option in System Preferences.

[image: Screenshot of System Preferences, Anywhere Option hidden]

So how can I enable "Allow apps downloaded from Anywhere" via Terminal? Using macOS Big Sur Ver 11.1

Comment: You can ignore the messages. But can you add a screenshot of the relevant part of System Preferences? Also, which version of macOS are you running?

Comment: Thanks, nohillside. I am running MacOS Big Sur Ver11.1. I am not sure how to add a screenshot into this text box.

Comment: Click on the little image icon on the top of the edit box while editing (the one to the right of `{}`)

Comment: If your objective is to run a single app downloaded from the internet, then why not just remove the quarantine extended attribute from the downloaded file.

Comment: Hi @David Anderson, any advise how to specifically do that? I tried searching for the solution you mentioned but I am not sure to identify the specific attribute and how to remove it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you download an application from the internet, then the following steps can be taken to open the application. Here the Startup application is used as an example.

I downloaded the Startup application from the SourceForge project [Startup for rEFInd](https://sourceforge.net/projects/startup-for-refind/). Here is my `Downloads` folder.

> Note: In Finder preferences, I have `Show all filename extensions` checked off.

[image]

When I double clicked on `Startup.app`, I received the following popup.

[image]

I selected the `Cancel` button. Next, I opened the `Security & Privacy` pane of the System Preferences application, as shown below.

[image]

Here, I selected `Open Anyway` and the the following popup occurred.

[image]

Here, I selected `Open` and the application opened.

> The above steps only had to be done once. Afterwards, the application could be opened by simply double clicking on the icon.

Note: The above steps did not remove the `com.apple.quarantine` extended attribute placed on any files or folders.

### How to Avoid the Above Steps

When a file is downloaded, the extended attribute named `com.apple.quarantine` is placed on the file. This is what initially kept the Startup the application from opening. The following steps can be taken to remove the `com.apple.quarantine` extended attribute from the application.

> If you want to test these steps, then you will probably what to put any existing Startup application in the trash, and download a new copy of the application.

Right click the application in the Finder window and select `New Terminal at Folder`, as shown below.

[image]

This will open a Terminal application window, as shown below.

[image]

Enter the following command, as shown in the image below.

```
xattr -rd com.apple.quarantine .
```

[image]

Next, close the Terminal application window. Now you can open the application normally.

Comment: This is much better than trying to disable SIP or modify things for all apps. +1 indeed

Comment: Thanks, David Anderson. Very clear step by step guide. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You don’t fix the output. Apple shipped both classes so Apple has to patch the libraries that `spctl` links against to “fix” that log message.

It doesn’t harm any function I can test, so it’s highly likely it has no bearing to your running of `spctl`. Your main problem is likely that you didn’t boot to recovery and use terminal app to change the security.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202491
- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/about-macos-recovery-mchl46d531d6/mac

You can’t enable or disable from the OS that’s running. *(Think of a surgeon, they can operate on another person, not themselves for safety sake.)*

Recovery is a different OS that can change entitlements on your daily driver OS when it’s not running. *(Or don’t do maintenance on your car/bike/airplane while it’s moving.)*

Comment: Hi bmike, thanks for reply. I am trying to use the "sudo spctl –master-enable" to enable the download other apps or anywhere option. But when I key in the command in terminal it does not work to allow "Anywhere" to appear but instead it just shows this long log. Can you advise?

Comment: I have no  idea what you’re doing. See the [tour] and our [help] on how to show your research and clearly describe your intended results. Your question is likely a duplicate of the dozens of ways to manage gatekeeper, but really we need more to go on other than you have the same harmless error message. Of course gatekeeper errors if you’re not booted to recovery is my first hunch, but let’s get more details

Comment: I was following this guide to open a Mac app from an unidentified developer. https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-app-unidentified-developer-3669596/. Open Terminal and enter the following code to get your Anywhere option:

sudo spctl --master-disable

Comment: I am wondering why I cannot get the anywhere button but get that long list of harmless message. I intend to get the Anywhere button to download a Mac app. Hope this clarifies. End result is to get the Anywhere button unhidden. Thanks.

Comment: Perfect. Once the question is edited to have all the necessary backstory, goals, trusted reviewers will vote to reopen the question - see the banner I placed so everyone knows that to do next. I can delete or edit my answer once the question is sorted..

Comment: Thanks bmike. Edited the question as per your advise.

Comment: IMHO the linked MacWorld article is just outdated

Comment: Thanks @nohillside I’ll keep it generic till we know the OS version. Lots of problems to unravel here other than OP needs possibly someone to help with triage / support